# Deleted/Modified/Added records from extjs store

Tags: extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, extjs-grid, extjs-stores

Im having the below store and modal for a grid in extjs 4.2.

```
    Ext.define('myapp.store.myStore',{
extends:'Ext.data.Store',
modal:'myapp.modal.myModal',
storeId:'myGridStore',
data:[],//used this only when trying inline data
proxy: {
type:'memory',
reader:{
type:'json',
}
}

});
Ext.define('myapp.modal.myModal',{
extends:'Ext.data.Modal',
fields:['bla','blha']
});
```

The mapping to the grid,store and modal looks fine and data is populated properly loaded in the grid.

The problem is when there are modifications to the store like

```
grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex)
```

or

```
grid.getStore().add(record)
```

im not able to get those through the

```
getRemovedRecords()
```

and

```
getNewRecords()
```

when i load the data into the store with the

```
grid.getStore().loadData(ajaxCallResponse).
```

It works fine when i give the data inline.

Pls help me understand what im doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
if(record.phantom  != true){
  record.phantom  = true;
}
store.loadData(record);
```

Check that phantom is true first then loadData, and try to use store.getNewRecords(), if phantom is true only the records will be there in getNewRecords().

Answer (score 0):

try store.getModifiedRecords() instead. This will get you the new and edited records. To check if its a new record just check the records "phantom" property which will equal true.

also, if getNewRecords() and getRemovedRecords() arent returning any records, try store.sync() after a record has been added/deleted.

Comment: Hi..thanks for d response...getModifiedRecords() always returns all the records in the store and the phanthom is false for all the records. Tried the sync as well after add or modify and even after the first time the data is loaded to the store from extjs ajax call..but getNewRecords() and getRemovedRecords() is always empty..

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new record to the store I had to set the phantom attribute to true (as suggested by @Naren Sathya in a previous answer) in order for the getModifiedRecords() method to actually list those newly added records:

```
// Create a new default record
var newServerConfig = new App.model.mConfigServer({
    id: idForNewRecord,
    server: 'server',
    port: 8443,
    username: 'user',
    password: ''
});

/* Setting the phantom property to 'true' will ensure this record will be listed
 * when trying to retrieve those new records with store.getModifiedRecords() later on
 */ 
newServerConfig.phantom = true;

// Add it to the store
storeServers.add(newServerConfig);
```